# Navigation drawer implementation with list fragments

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to implement a navigation drawer with multiple listfragments, how can i do this? I spent time searching online but couldnt find anything related to it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean you want the `DrawerLayout` to have multiple `ListFragments` instead of just a single `ListView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When implementing the NavigationDrawer, use its onDrawerItemSelected method to switch Fragments:

```
    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(final int pos) {

         // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new ListFragmentOne();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ListFragmentTwo();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ListFragmentThree();
            break;
        }

        // content_frame is a FrameLayout inside the layout of your activity - this is where the fragment will be put
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(pos, true);
        // do stuff like closing the drawer...
    }
```

**I am not sure though if the NavigationDrawer even supports ListFragments. If not, simply use normal Fragments containing a ListView.**